# There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace : Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed `latest version of Megento 2`, everything is working fine frontend, backend and functionality.

I have one issue with  `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, when I run this command in terminal I get below exception .

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Is there any thing I missed during installation or I need to install some package to let it working?

Comment: Magento other commans work or not ?

Comment: Check composer.json and module.xml exist correctly under all your current modules.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please mention **`setup_version`** in your **module.xml** file.
Your **module.xml** file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

You need to give full permission to both **var** and **pub** folders recursively.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: In my case I was missing the entire etc/module.xml file when I got that error. Adding the file allowed the command to run correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Giving full control (read/write/execute) to **var** and **pub** directory should solve this issue.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

You may also try running the command using **sudo**.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade is working fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add an answer because the others doens't cover all the problems that could generate this error :

> There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

in general.

This error could be caused by permission as said in others answer but we could have other scenario.

- The absense of : etc/module.xml
- An error in /etc/module.xml or in /etc/di.xml or others xml extensions under /etc

If you know other scenario please comment this answer.
Hope this help.

Comment: Between composer create-project and bin/magento setup:install there is only a restricted set of available commands. After install is done, all commands are in place. I don't know yet why this is happening (maybe because there is no database or config file for cache yet..), as all the modules in vendor (which imlements the commands) are present. For example there is no config:set (which i need to run before setup:install), also no cache namespace, no indexing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the directory of *var* and remove *pub/static* directory , it will work *bin/magento* `setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I encounterd the same error while running commands related to magento. I was missing double_quotes(") in module.xml file of the custom module. So check module.xml file for any typos and setup_version.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more hint check the 'MAGE_MODE' value in env.php it should be correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error can be seen in the command output: **`php -f bin/magento`**.

This will work for most errors like `There are no commands defined in the "..." namespace.`.

---

A fairly common cause is an error in the `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

simple RUN `php bin/magento` this will show you details where it is broken