# InvalidArgumentException: There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento version 2.1 without sample data. I have an issue regarding the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. It creates an error of

> [InvalidArgumentException]: There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

I have attempt all solutions but nothing works for me. Please sort out my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace : Magento 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935850/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following:

1. First, check your deployment configuration if it is in developer mode. You can do that by using `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`. If it is not in developer mode, switch to it by using `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.
2. Next, delete everything in the `generated` folder, except the `.htaccess` file.
3. Then refresh your Magento website.

That should regenerate all the classes needed to run `setup:upgrade` in the `generated` folder.

Hope this helps!